# Can I use metro design to style my app

Tags: microsoft-metro

Some while ago, Microsoft patented the Metro style design for applications (if I'm not mistaken). In the press publications back then, some articles talked about existing applications in metro style which could be forced to switch design by Microsoft.

For a new application I'm going to build, I was looking towards a metro style interface to be able to easily adopt it to Windows 8 as soon as it get's here. Are there any things to take into account when choosing this path? Basically what I want to avoid is Microsoft contacting me in a year or so, telling me to swop my design because they don't like me using Metro. Although I'd find that weird since they seem to be pushing everyone towards metro styled apps, but I just want to be sure.

Comment: If this wiki is reliable, Microsoft is planning to expand Metro rather than replace it, so I think you're safe. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metro_(design_language) But any way, If your interface is only loosly coupled to the logic of your application, you can always adopt other means of interfacing without too much effort.

Comment: Design will be loosely coupled, but if I can prevent the extra work now, I'd rather choose a different design alltogether. Thanks though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The patenting of Metro is to prevent competitors from copying or closely emulating the design, functionality and/or behaviour. As a developer of apps on their devices using their operating system, you are allowed all the rights to make apps using the Metro theme.

The patent application is simply to protect their research and concepts from being ripped off by competitors. It is a common practice, you have nothing to be concerned about.

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking, but I wasn't sure. Thanks.